# Magento Total saleble qty displays wrong count

Tags: magento2.3, multi-source-inventory

I've magento setup with MSI with 2 sources and both are assigned to stocks as well.

But In product grid **Total Salable Qty** displays wrong count.

```
It suppose to be sum of total available sources.
```

Check below screen.

[image]

Here is screen of product form.

[image]

Anyone has gone through it ? Any help would be appreciated.

**Sources Configurations**
[image]

**Stock Configurations**
[image]

Comment: Didi you try reindex?

Comment: @SerhiiHavrylchuk, Obviously I did that.

Comment: Do you have minQty (i.e. "Out-of-Stock Treshold") set for the products? For example a minQty = 1 would reduce the saleable Qty by 1. That's not MSI related just the usual Magento behaviour.

Comment: @HelgeB, No didn't set any minimum qty for product. Its default settings.

Comment: @Vivek Can you share your Manage Stocks and Manage Sources configuration screenshots?

Comment: @ToanNguyen Did you check git URL ? I've posted over there.

Comment: @ToanNguyen, I've updated it here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debug and clearing all test data issue was still there.

After that I've disabled 3rd party modules and came to know that it's caused by **Premium ERP**. :(

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't reproduce this in my system but I'm really curious what's up there, I stepped a little into the calculation of this field. Although this don't solve your problem, it might bring some light into the situation.

There are 3 values from which the salable quantity is calculated: The quantity in stock (which is the sum of all sources of the stock), the reserved quantity (from orders) and the configured minimum quantity.

The formula is: quantity in stock + reserved quantity - minimum quantity

With this SQL statements you can check the situation in your database:

```
-- quantity in stock
select quantity from inventory_stock_[YOUR_STOCK_ID] where sku = '[YOUR_SKU]';

-- reserved quantity
select SUM (quantity) from inventory_reservation where sku = '[YOUR_SKU]';

-- configuration for minimum quantity in stock
select min_qty, use_config_min_qty from cataloginventory_stock_item 
where product_id = (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity where sku = '[YOUR_SKU]');
```

Please run this statements for your product and share the results with us.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I did try earlier what you suggested. After debug and clearing magento  with fresh install i find that issue caused by **Premium ERP** :(

Comment: Good to hear that you have solved your problem and that Magento's MSI is working :-)